# Using pexpect to log into a docker container

Tags: python, pexpect

I am trying to get into a kubernetes pod to execute some commands.

Manually - it goes through

```
➜ kubectl exec -it pg-postgresql-0 -n ns-sql -c postgresql -- bash
I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$
I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$
I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ exit
```

When I try through pexpect:

```
➜ cat sql.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pexpect

cmd = "kubectl exec -it pg-postgresql-0 -n ns-sql -c postgresql -- bash"
child = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
child.expect('I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ ')
child.sendline('psql -U postgres')
child.expect('user postgres: ')
child.sendline('passW0rd')
child.expect('postgres=#')
child.interact()
```

This is what I see:

```
➜ ./sql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    child.expect('I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ ')
  File "/home/bhakta/dev/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 344, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async_)
  File "/home/bhakta/dev/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 372, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/home/bhakta/dev/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 181, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/home/bhakta/dev/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 144, in timeout
    raise exc
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7f086ebc8e90>
command: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
args: ['/usr/local/bin/kubectl', 'exec', '-it', 'pg-postgresql-0', '-n', 'ns-sql', '-c', 'postgresql', '--', 'bash']
buffer (last 100 chars): b'I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ \r\x1b[KI have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ '
before (last 100 chars): b'I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ \r\x1b[KI have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ '
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 178145
child_fd: 5
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ ')
```

Any suggestions on debugging this? Why is it timing out even though it seems to be seeing the exepcted prompt

Comment: I might use `kubectl port-forward` to get access to the PostgreSQL socket and then use an ordinary PostgreSQL client library for this.  That will be much easier to both set up and test locally.  In general I'd avoid trying to script `kubectl exec`.

Comment: `pexpect.expect(s)` would handle `s` as regex pattern so you need to escape the `$` char as in `'I have no name!@pg-postgresql-0:/$ '`.